# GitHub icons missing

Tags: github, icons

Is anybody else's GitHub missing icons? There are no JS errors, and from what I can tell looking at `resources` in Chrome developer tools, no 404 errors.

[image]

Comment: It's rendering with icons for me.  What browser are you using?

Comment: Chrome latest `Version 21.0.1180.79`

Comment: Missing the icons here too, full uninstall and reinstall didn't help. TheVerge.com is also missing it's typekit fonts.

Comment: I am also facing the same issue. I am on google chrome 21.0.1180.82 beta / mac

Answer (score 11, accepted):

These icons are done with the font - 'Octicons Regular', so that won't be loading for you for some reason. It is all done with CSS so shouldn't require js to work. See this page for details:

https://github.com/styleguide/css/7.0

Perhaps try checking that you don't have remote font loading disabled (there is a command line switch I think), or a bad version of this font cached, or some other font issue - you can check what has loaded if you enable the inspector and look in resources for that frame, there should be a Fonts listing with the Octicons font listed. You could also try downloading the font and installing locally.

If you cannot load other fonts, probably it's a setting rather than this specific font.

You might be able to see the font loading settings here:

```
chrome://about
```

I think the setting you need is

```
--enable-remote-fonts
```

which you can run from the command line to turn them on again (on by default now).

Comment: Still nothing. Cleared all cache and cookies, closed Chrome, and still not working. Here is a screenshot of what I see when I visit the `styleguide`. http://i.imgur.com/RYYBZ.png

Comment: Perhaps try testing another browser, to see if this is specific to your browser (try Safari for example, or Firefox). And also try testing here in Chrome: http://www.google.com/webfonts .

Comment: Yeah, all the fonts on http://www.google.com/webfonts look the same. There must be a setting I accidentally disabled in Chrome. Confirmed in Safari works. Any idea where this setting is in Chrome?

Comment: How do I run `--enable-remote-fonts `. What application runs this command? Thanks.

Comment: Magically fixed today. No idea what changed.

Answer (score 5):

[This](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=120929) seems to be related. Doing the steps provided in comment 13 fixed the issue for me:

```
$ atsutil databases -removeUser
$ atsutil server -shutdown
$ atsutil server -ping
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use a plugin that can change the style of the page, such as Stylish.In custom style change the font-family, may cause this problem.Sorry for my English.